# Generic Insert or update method

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have a generic method that updates or inserts and entity. I don't understand the purpose of the if statement here. The comment tells me what it is for but it is not clear to me.

Why is the namespace checked against System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies. I thought that all entities retrieved via entity framework would be under this namespace? And why would we check the base type for null?

```
public virtual T InsertOrUpdate(T e)
{
DbSet<T> dbSet = Context.Set<T>();

DbEntityEntry<T> entry;
if (e.GetType().BaseType != null 
    && e.GetType().Namespace == "System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies")
{
    //The entity being added is already a proxy type that supports lazy 
    //loading - just get the context entry
    entry = Context.Entry(e);
}
else
{
    //The entity being added has been created using the "new" operator. 
    //Generate a proxy type to support lazy loading  and attach it
    T instance = dbSet.Create();
    instance.ID = e.ID;
    entry = Context.Entry(instance);
    dbSet.Attach(instance);

    //and set it's values to those of the entity
    entry.CurrentValues.SetValues(e);
    e = instance;
}

entry.State = e.ID == default(int) ?
                        EntityState.Added :
                        EntityState.Modified;

    return e;
}
```

Comment: why would we check the base type for null? If you want to initialize it,  or before you make a function call,  or to avoid looping thru an empty list or before adding an element to it.

Comment: @Juniar all the entities that use this method inherit from a base class that has an Id field so that they can be used in this generic method. So T has a basetype called "Base" which is never null. I guess this check in the if statement is pointless as it will always not be equal to null.

Comment: @TheGeneral would it be preferable just to copy and paste the same code for every CRUD operation?